# Abstract baseclass' generic data type return

Tags: java, generics, return, abstract

I'm working on a project where one of the demands is that we use a generic data type.(other requirements: abstract class, inheritance, save/load functions, aggregation & compostion)

I figured I'd make a library to fill out all of the requirements, had a hard time coming up with a good idea for when/where to use a generic data type and then it seemed obvious that if I have a class called **Media** and two subclasses called **Book** and **CD** length for book is in int(pages), length for CD is in double(minutes & seconds)

I figured it would help to make this in Media:

```
    public abstract class Media<T>{
        private T length;
        //lots of other variables & methods here, took out for sake of cutting to the chase

        public T getLength(){
            return length;
        }

        public void setLength(T length){
            this.length = length;
        }
    }
```

**QUESTIONS:**

But the issue now is that how can it return a type when it doesn't recieve one in getLength and thus doesn't know which type it is unless it is set somehow? Or would a solution be to make every subclass call this function once in the constructor to set it?

Can I override the `private T length;` variable somehow in the subclasses **Book** and **CD**? Just to set their type so that the getLength would function the way it should, or is there any other solution to this?

There is the option of using a generic data type elsewhere, but I just don't know where it would be appropriate, my professors are nitpicking even past the requirements so they've let me know that they will fail me if they think that something is "not used properly" or "not a good example" even though "etiquette" isn't a requirement.

Comment: Why are you not using `Media` as a interface?

Comment: It doesn't receive a type in `getLength()`, but it received one when you created the `Media<Something>` instance. Can you show an example of the code in which you intend to use this `Media` class?

Comment: @MuratK. Abstract class is a requirement

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, if I call getLength() through an instance of Book, it should return an int, and instance of CD should return double. But how can it do that? Or rather how can I make it do that? While at the same time keeping it a generic type in Media.

Comment: Well, the classes would have been specified as `class Book extends Media<Integer>` and `class CD extends Media<Double>`. Also, it won't return `int` and `double`, it will return `Integer` and `Double`.

Comment: Ohhh, that was such a simple solution geez. Thanks! If you make an answer with this I'll give you the points! :)

Comment: For `Media` to be useful though, it needs to be usable as an umbrella class. If you plan on doing numbery things with `getLength()` later in a list of mixed `Book` and `CD`, you should declare `Media` as `public class Media<T extends Number>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andy Turner for the solution, and the contributions of the others, but he gave the answer that helped, which was this:

What I did:

```
class Book extends Media{
...
}
class CD extends Media{
...
}
```

What I should've added:

```
class Book extends Media<Integer>{
...
}
class CD extends Media<Double>{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is good case of covariant types and Java 1.5 or later supports this behaviour. Generics is optional as return types are covariant, but can be added if needed and should work just the same.

```
public class CovariantTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Media book = new Book();
    assert book.getLength().getClass() == Integer.class;
    Media cd = new Cd();
    assert cd.getLength().getClass() == Double.class;

    //Just for sake of being complete
    assert book.getLength().getClass() == Number.class; // AssertionError
    assert cd.getLength().getClass() == Number.class; // AssertionError

  }
}

abstract class Media {
  private Number length;

  public Number getLength() {
    return length;
  }

}

class Book extends Media {

  @Override
  public Integer getLength() {
    return 5;
  }
}

class Cd extends Media {
  @Override
  public Double getLength() {
    return 5.01;
  }
}
```